# How to get attributes from Firebase database list

Tags: android

[Database format image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM5EE.png)

i have users class and requests class , in user profile i need to display
the requests that belong to this user , so from the image above.

I already have the current userID

```
        uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

i need to search in all child "requests" in the attribute owner to see 
if it matches the current user id

from what I've understood i need to write the following code

```
       myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("requests");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            List<String> requestes_uid = new ArrayList<String>(); // Result will be holded Here
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {


            /*
                if (owner.equals(uid))
                {
                    // this request belong to this user
                    modelrequests_list.add(request);
                }
            */
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

so what should i do exactly

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your for loop

```
Request request = postSnapshot.getValue();
If (request.getOwner() == uid){
   modelrequests_list.add(request);
}
```

I didn't test this code, but your answer should be something like that.